# Deliberatly trigger a compilation error in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is there a way to deliberatly trigger a compilation error when a certain condition is satisfied on Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8tk0xsk%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Kenny: you may want to post that as an answer instead. It may just be what André is looking for...

Comment: What *programming language* are you using? Your question makes no sense without that detail.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the #error pre-processor feature.

You use it like such:

```
#ifdef WIN32
    ... code for windows
#else
    #error only windows is supported
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you can use macros like the following to cause a compile time assert when a specified constant condition is false

```
#define COMPILE_ASSERT(expr) extern int __assertutil[(expr) != 0]

COMPILE_ASSERT(42 != 8);  // Fine
COMPILE_ASSERT(42 == 8);  // Error
```

This works because in the case that the expression is false it will have a constant value of 0.  Arrays in C++ can not have a constant size of 0 and it leads to a compilation error.

Comment: This is the closest to what I was looking for, but in C#

Answer (score 2):

how about the [compiler directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8tk0xsk%28VS.80%29.aspx) #error?

Answer (score 0):

There are language specific pre-processor directives. In C#:

```
#define DEBUG class MainClass  {
    static void Main() 
    {
#if DEBUG
#error DEBUG is defined
#endif
    } 
}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5hedts0.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

int i = (float)(5.0);

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you're looking for a way to validate the source code before compilation. If so, you could use a pre-build step and fail it (exit with a code other than 0) to abort compilation.